# best number of rows to delete in a delete query

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server and I have a very big table.

If we use `delete from table` query we have jump in transaction log.
I should use a query like this

```
delete top (@count) from table
```

And then I should put that in a while in my asp.net code.

My question is what is the best `@count` amount to achieve these goals:

- The table would be able to respond other queries during delete process
- No jump in transaction log file
- Super fast for deleting all of rows (I have hundreds of thousands of rows)

Added information:
This is a item_in_tags table which stores item id and tag id so it has many many rows when I want to re tag all items I need to delete every thing in it and then enter the data to the table I cannot have a very large transaction because jump in transaction log is not acceptable for host and I have not shrink permission.
I want to keep size of transaction small and fast but I want to get best performance too and in retagging process I don't want to get down time for problems like table locking, etc.

Comment: If you want delete all the table why dont use `TRUNCATE TABLE`.

Comment: Befor you can truncate a table, you need to remove any foreign key contraints to that table, if any

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that and also I didn't use that!

Comment: There's a **5000 rows** limit as to how SQL Server handles **locking** - for 5000 rows (or less) in a transaction, it will lock the individual rows being deleted - if your transaction deletes more than 5000 rows at once, SQL Server will do a **lock escalation** and lock **the entire table exclusively**, meaning you can't even read from it anymore. That might be one threshold to keep in mind when deleting in batches ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are different scenarios that seem to fall within the scope of what you are asking:

1. You want to delete everything in the table. Then `truncate table` is the right approach.
2. Your delete query needs to do a full table scan to identify the rows being deleted. Then a larger number would probably be better, to reduce the number of full table scans.
3. You have very complex triggers or cascading operations on the table. In that case, "1" might be the best answer.
4. The other queries are modifying the table, so you have the potential issue of locking conflicts and timeouts. In that case, you might need to wait until the system is quieter to do your work.
5. The other operations are read-only and don't need to see the deletes. In that case, selecting into another table, and using `sp_rename` when the table is not in use might be the most efficient solution.

And, there are no doubt other scenarios as well. My advice is to choose a number such as 100 or 1000 and just go with it. Reduce the number if the deletes appear to be interfering with other operations.

Comment: @MohammadHa . . . Based on your modification, I would suggest (5).  Recreate the table you need and then either delete/rename or truncate/insert to put the correct data into it.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft used to default to 1000 rows for many operations, now it defaults, in SSIS among other places, to 10000 rows at a time. Many developers use 10000 as the number of rows for a large transaction but you may want to play with that number to see (on your system with its own memory and hard disk) to see if a larger, or smaller number, finishes faster.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could try this approach by inserting the records you want to keep in a temp table and then truncate your actual table. Then, transfer back those temp table records into your actual table. Not sure how much perform gain you would achieve from this, but definitely would recommend doing a `BACKUP` before doing this:

```
SELECT item_id,
       tag_id
INTO #Holdingtable
FROM item_in_tags 
WHERE items_id IN (***items you want to keep****)         


TRUNCATE TABLE item_in_tags

INSERT into item_in_tags     
SELECT 
     item_id,
     tag_id
FROM #Holdingtable
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to delete the records fast right? **Truncate table** would be the best option especially if you don't want to log the data. If there are some records that you would like to keep from that table, I would insert those records into a temporary table first and then insert them back to the actual table after the table has been truncated.

Comment: My problem in using delete from table query was jumping database size because of log file. So I had to make transactions smaller and do delete 1000 from table many times. Now you say Truncate table isn't logged! Really? If I Truncate all table no jump happens?

Answer (score 0):

User `Truncate Table myTable` if you don't have triggers on that table that need to fire.  Think of this as basically slapping an END-OF-FILE marker at the top of the table.

Comment: I can't understand last sentence would you please explain last sentence more? Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't do a row by row delete, it Truncate just resets it so their are no rows in the table.